# Divide function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm trying to use the `Divide` function in SSAS:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj873944(v=sql.110).aspx

But I have to support SQL server 2008 and it looks like this is not available. The initial problem I am having is that when I add a case statement to a measure calculation the performance of the query is VERY poor. It's been suggested to use this `divide` function.

The statement to create member is:

```
Create Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[AvgSentiment] As 
   CASE 
      WHEN ([Measures].[SentimentCount]) > 0 THEN  [Measures].[SentimentSum] / [Measures].[SentimentCount] 
      WHEN([Measures].[SentimentCount]) = 0 THEN  0  
   END
  , VISIBLE =1
  , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'vw_CUBE_FACT'  ;
```

Which I tried replacing with:

```
Create Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[AvgSentiment] As 
    Divide ([Measures].[SentimentSum], [Measures].[SentimentCount], 0)
  , VISIBLE =1
  , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'vw_CUBE_FACT'
```

I also tried:

```
Create Member CurrentCube.[Measures].[AvgSentiment] As 
  IIF(
    [Measures].[SentimentCount] = 0
   , 0
   , [Measures].[SentimentSum]/[Measures].[SentimentCount]
 )
 , VISIBLE =1
 , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'vw_SEAMS_CUBE_FACT'
```

This also ate up a tonne of CPU / Memory.

Comment: Please show us your attempted query, thanks.

Comment: Hmm this is hard as it eats up 100% of my memory on my machine. I'll try to get it but it's hard :-(

Comment: Tried `ISNULL(numerator/NULLIF(denominator,0),alternateresult)`?

Comment: Weird I'm getting this error: Error occurred: MdxScript(CUBE) (1, 416) The '[NULLIF]' function does not exist.

Comment: Hmm I guess SSAS/MDX doesn't allow for all T-SQL functions.

Comment: @TT. `mdx` is a separate language!

Comment: @whytheq Now I know =). I responded to the sql-server tag...

Answer (score 3):

Divide won't make a huge difference.

Your third attempt is almost what you want. What you aim to do with cube measures is make them "sparse". My interpretation of this is that you want them to only exist in the parts of the cube where they should exist - everywhere else the cube space should be empty - this is achieved by using `null` in your measure rather than 0:

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measures].[AvgSentiment] As 
  IIF(
    [Measures].[SentimentCount] = 0
   , NULL //<<got rid of the 0
   , [Measures].[SentimentSum]
    /[Measures].[SentimentCount]
 )
 , VISIBLE =1
 , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'vw_SEAMS_CUBE_FACT'
```

`IIF` generally performs better than `CASE` so better this than adapting your attempt using `CASE`.

If the above still performs badly then I suspect you need to investigate the performance of `[Measures].[SentimentCount]` - how is this calculated?

Comment: @GregGalloway Thanks. I'm still sort of feeling around with the specifics of this concept of calculation sparsity - do you know any good references where myself, and questioner, could get some more detail on it?